# Printing out 2D array [,]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, concatenation

I have a **2D array** (`array`) and try to print out (`Console.WriteLine`) its elements separated by semicolon `;`. I.e. having an array like

```
MyType[,] array = new MyType[,] 
{
    {item11, item12, item13},
    {item21, item22, item23},
};
```

I'm looking for the outcome

```
item11;item12;item13
item21;item22;item23
```

My attempts are:

```
for (int y = 0; y < (array.GetLength(0)); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
    {
        //--> This way it works however I get the final ; 
        // after the last element which I do not need
        Console.Write(array[y, x] + ";"); 
        //--> This way I get only semicolons and no array elements
        Console.Write(String.Join(";", array)); 
    }
    Console.WriteLine('\r');
}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: What is `array`? What are its values? What is the expected output? What do you get?

Comment: *"How to resolve it?"* Resolve what exactly?

Comment: @Zaur Bakhramov: I've edited your question (*example* and *desired outcome* provided), next time, please, be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing item after item (in fact, you don't concatenate the items but output them to console):

```
for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); ++y) {
  if (y > 0)
    Console.WriteLine();

  for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); ++x) {
    if (x > 0) 
      Console.Write(";");   

    Console.Write(array[y, x]); 
  }
}
```

For

```
int[,] array = new int[,] {
  { 1, 2, 3},
  { 4, 5, 6},
};
```

the code above prints out

```
1;2;3
4;5;6
```

If you want to have `string` (which you can print out later), change `Console` to `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); ++y) {
  if (y > 0)
    sb.AppendLine();

  for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); ++x) {
    if (x > 0) 
      sb.Append(";");   

    sb.Append(array[y, x]); 
  }
}

string result = sb.ToString();

...

Console.Write(result);
```

**Side note**: Please, notice how much easier it is to work with a jagged array (`[][]` instead of `[,]`): just two `Join`s:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array
  .Select(line => string.Join(";", line))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MoreLinq extensions, it has [a `Batch` operator](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) you can use to simplify this. This is [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.Batch/).

Using the `Batch` operator, the solution looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] array =
            {
                { 0, 1,  2,  3 },
                { 4, 5,  6,  7 },
                { 8, 9, 10, 11 }
            };

            foreach (var row in array.Cast<int>().Batch(array.GetLength(1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", row));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could write an extension method for iterating the rows of a two dimensional array (using `Batch()`):

```
public static class TwoDimensionalArrayExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rows<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        return array.Cast<T>().Batch(array.GetLength(1));
    }
}
```

The the code becomes more readable:

```
foreach (var row in array.Rows())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", row));
}
```